# Is there a "sample tube manual eject" switch that can be externally accessed on Perseverance?

Tags: mars, perseverance

In the (unlikely) event that Perseverance stops operating before 2026, can the sample fetch rover forcibly detach the already full sample tubes by accessing a manual switch on the rover? Would it make sense to include one?

Comment: Note that Perseverance does not have enough onboard storage to store the sample containers; they are instead cached on the surface of Mars. So, there would only be a limited number of sample containers inside Perseverance anyway, only the ones that were recently sampled and not yet cached.